How to calculate the capacity from a given list of currents,RelativeTime and Time which are obtained through experiment?
I'm working on machine Learning Project to build a model that predicts Remaining useful life time of a battery using NASA dataset which consists data of four 18650 batteries (identified as RW9,RW10,RW11,RW12).
I need to calculate the capacity term and also the Number of cycles.
The Dataset description is as follows:
Data Structure:
Each of the .mat files contains a Matlab data structure called “data”.
The top level of this structure contains 3 fields:

procedure (A string naming the experimental procedure)

description (A more detailed text description of the experimental procedure)

step (An array of structs containing cycling data)
Within the step array you will find a struct with the following fields:

comment (string description of step)

type (one character identifier of step: ‘C’ = Charging, ‘D’ = Discharging, ‘R’ = Resting
(current = 0))

relativeTime (vector of sample time in seconds, referenced to the beginning of the current
step)

time (vector of sample time in seconds, referenced to the beginning of the experiment)

voltage (vector of sample voltage in units of Volts)

current (vector of sample current in units of Amps)

temperature (vector of sample temperature in units of degrees C)

date (date and time at which the current step was started in dd-Mon-yyyy HH:MM:SS
format)


Each of the .Rda files contains the same information as the Matlab data files. The step data structure in each
.Rda file is formated as a dataframe wherein each row represents a unique charging, discharging, or resting step
in the battery cycling experiment.
https://data.nasa.gov/Raw-Data/Randomized-Battery-Usage-1-Random-Walk/ugxu-9kjx/about_data
Batteries are cycled using three types of reference profiles:

A low current discharge at 0.04A is used to observe the batteries open circuit voltage as a function of SOC
This profile is identified in the step data structure with the comment field equal to “low current
discharge at 0.04A”
Resting periods that occur immediately before and after the low current discharge are identified with
the comment field = “rest prior low current discharge” and comment field = “rest post low
current discharge” respectively
A reference charge and discharge cycle is used to observe the battery capacity after every 1500 RW steps
cycles
Batteries are first charged at 2A (constant current), until they reach 4.2V, at which time the charging
switches to a constant voltage mode and continues charging the batteries until the charging current
falls below 0.01A.
This step is identified with the comment field = “reference charge”
Batteries are then rested for a period of time with no current draw
This step is identified with the comment field = “rest post reference charge”
Batteries are then discharged at 2A until the battery voltage crosses 3.2V
This step is identified with the comment field = “reference discharge”
Batteries are then rested for a period of time
This step is identified with the comment field = “rest post reference discharge”
A pulsed current discharge of fully charged batteries is performed after every 3000 RW steps in order to
benchmark changes to battery transient dynamics. The pulsed current discharge consist of a 1A load
applied for 10 minutes, followed by 20 minutes of no load.
This discharging profile is identified by alternating steps of comment = “pulsed load (rest)” and
comment = “pulsed load (discharge)”
A resting period after either a pulsed discharge or a pulsed charge is denoted by comment = “rest
post pulsed load or charge”
A pulsed current charge of recently discharged batteries is performed after every 3000 RW cycles in order
to benchmark changes to battery transient dynamics. The pulsed current charge consists of a 1A charging
current applied for 10 minutes, followed by 20 minutes of rest.
This charging profile is identified by alternating steps of comment = “pulsed charge (rest)” and
comment = “pulsed charge (charge)”
A resting period after either a pulsed discharge or a pulsed charge is denoted by comment = “rest
post pulsed load or charge”

The random walk (RW) mode of battery cycling consists of:

Selecting a charging or discharging current at random from the set {-4.5A, -3.75A, -3A, -2.25A, -1.5A,
-0.75A, 0.75A, 1.5A, 2.25A, 3A, 3.75A, 4.5A}. Negative currents are associated with charging and positive
currents indicate discharging.
The selected current setpoint is applied until either the battery voltage goes outside the range (3.2V -
4.2V) or 5 minutes has passed.
These steps are identified with the comment field = “discharge (random walk)” and comment field =
“charge (random walk)”
After each charging or discharging period, there will be a <1s period of rest while a new charging or
discharging current setpoint is selected.
This steps is identified with the comment field = “rest (random walk)”
Steps 2 and 3 are repeated 1500 times, then characterization cycles are preformed to benchmark battery


Hello and welcome.  Please would you edit your question to put a web link so we can see what you're describing?  (Is it that NASA dataset?) Currently you have a "file:" link to your own computer.   Thank you.

"started in dd-Mon-yyyy HH:MM:SS format" I thought NASA used ISO8601.

I have given a public url to access the data set.yes,The dataset is a NASA dataset
